# How to dynamically modify QP rate limit in ConnectX-6 Infiniband/VPI adapter

Tags: bandwidth, pci-e, nic, infiniband, rdma

I have a ConnectX-6 Infiniband/VPI Adapter. I can setup the hardware rate limit when creating a qp like this:

```
...
ibv_qp_attr.ah_attr.static_rate = 7; // set qp rate limit to 40Gbps
...
ibv_modify_qp(qp, &ibv_qp_attr, flags); 
...
```

But I cannot dynamically change the qp rate limit later using the above code after creating the qp.

I also checked the `ibv_modify_qp_rate_limit()` API, but it keeps return EINVAL when I try to set the rate limit using this API:

```
struct ibv_qp_rate_limit_attr rl_attr;
memset(&rl_attr, 0, sizeof(rl_attr));
rl_attr.rate_limit = 100;
ibv_modify_qp_rate_limit(qp, &rl_attr); // returns EINVAL
```

Am I using the API right? How can I dynamically change the hardware rate limit of a qp? (or set the global hardware rate limit).

Answer (score 0):

The `rate_limit` attribute is in Kbps.  I suspect 100 Kbps is too low a limit for the device to handle (the original `static_rate` interface can only go down to 1X single data rate, which is 2.5 Gbps).  You can check by using the

```
ibv_query_device_ex(context, &device_attr)
```

API and making sure your requested rate limit is between

```
device_attr.packet_pacing_caps.qp_rate_limit_min
```

and

```
device_attr.packet_pacing_caps.qp_rate_limit_max
```

Comment: qp_rate_limit_min and qp_rate_limit_max are both 0 in my environment. Does this mean this device does not support limiting rate?

Comment: I'm not sure. From looking a bit more at the ibv_query_device_ex() documentation, it seems that API may be for raw packet QPs only.  I'm not sure there's any way to modify the static rate for a connected QP after the QP is set up, although it may be possible to use the alternate path mechanism to set up a second destination with the same address but a different static_rate and then flip over to that.